# Top 3 Values for Multiple Categories based on hours in a week

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, pivot-table

I'm working on a charging matrix where project managers can input time to the top three contracts in each category based on a week to week basis. Right now I have a pivot table with the categories (Production, Spares, Development) with multiple contracts that were charged that week. I manually select the top three from each category and copy into a table where I have formulas creating charge numbers for the project managers to use.

The question is, is there a way I can automate selecting the top 3 contracts from each category based on number of hours for that specific week?

[Pivot Table & Charging Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN2J8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LARGE() to get the top 3 (large(data,1) etc)

Then use index() and match() to get the contract names.

I have made a simple example here, but it will not deal with duplicate results in the hours if they are in the top 3...
There are solutions to that already posted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to automate the process of finding the top 3 contracts under each category and then create the charge number based on the results.

You can do so by creating a new pivot table as demonstrated below, put the **Category Name** and **Contract Name** in the `Rows` field, and put the **Hours** in the `Values` field, then right click anywhere within the Row Labels column of the pivot table, go to **Filter** -> **Top 10...** -> enter 3 in the second field, then you should have the top three contracts for each category.

[image: Pivot Top 3]

> P.s. You can choose to sort the hours from largest to smallest, and choose NOT to show the subtotals for each category.

Once you have the list, you can enter your formula (I presume you used a formula) in corresponding cells in column H (as in my example) to create the desired charge number.

Comment: Great thanks! One more question, if i were to sort from largest to smallest, or even filter the top three.. Is there a formula I can use to pull those contract names without simply linking the cells

Comment: I have been linking the cells but sometimes it breaks because of different contracts coming in on different weeks.

Comment: The logic behind the charge number is simply that the formula vlookups the charger number and thats it. Every week I simply look at the highest contracts and manually type it into a table to then use the vlookup formula

Comment: I've thought many times how I can automate the process and I can't happen think of anything unfortunately

Comment: @JohathanMartin I am still not very clear where is the problem. You should update your post to show the current formula you used to find the charge number (as you mentioned it should be a VLOOKUP), and let us know why it is not working in certain scenario.